# Getting System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf after deploying site on remote server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am new to C# and .NET, I have developed C# MVC3 (using Entity Framework) Website on my local machine and publish site to remote server.

```
2018-07-26 10:38:10,103 [6] INFO  MySite.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Inside homecontroller Index () 
2018-07-26 10:38:18,007 [10] INFO  MySite.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Inside homecontroller Index () 
2018-07-26 10:38:29,742 [8] INFO  MySite.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Inside homecontroller Login Post () 
2018-07-26 10:38:32,148 [8] ERROR MySite.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Exception inside Login () :   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MySite.Controllers.homeController.Login(FormCollection form) in C:\Users\DevDesk\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project1\MySite\Controllers\homeController.cs:line 115
2018-07-26 10:38:32,231 [5] INFO  MySite.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Inside homecontroller Index ()
```

Here is my connection string :

```
 // Local Machine Connection String

 <add name="UserProfileDBEntities" 
 connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.UserProfileModel.csdl|res://*/Models.UserProfileModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.UserProfileModel.msl;
 provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
 provider connection string=&quot;
 Data Source=LAPTOP-H0PPTKKU;
 Initial Catalog=test_db;
 User ID=dev_user;
 Password=dev_user;
 MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

 // Remote Server Connection String

 <add name="UserProfileDBEntities"
 connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.UserProfileModel.csdl|res://*/Models.UserProfileModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.UserProfileModel.msl;
 provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
 provider connection string=&quot;
 Data Source=DESKTOP-MP9NGB9;
 Initial Catalog=prod_db;
 User ID=prod_user;
 Password=prod_user;
 MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Now I am getting below error :

```
2018-07-26 10:58:32,176 [20] INFO  MySite.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Inside homecontroller Index () 
2018-07-26 10:58:59,757 [20] INFO  MySite.Controllers.UserController [(null)] - Inside UserController list() 
2018-07-26 10:58:59,766 [23] INFO  MySite.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Inside homecontroller Index () 
2018-07-26 10:59:08,195 [23] INFO  MySite.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Inside homecontroller Login Post () 
2018-07-26 10:59:22,986 [23] ERROR MySite.Controllers.homeController [(null)] - Exception inside Login () :   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

What wrong with the setting or I need to do any changes in app.config file..?

Comment: Try this `<add name="UserProfileDBEntities"  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.UserProfileModel.csdl|res://*/Models.UserProfileModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.UserProfileModel.msl; data source=DESKTOP-MP9NGB9;initial catalog=prod_db;user id=prod_user;password=prod_user;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Whats the difference ?

Comment: did u tested? is working or not?

Comment: No its not working

Comment: your app is working on local or not? or only gives error after deployment

Comment: Yes right its working on local

Comment: just remove metadata from connectionString and try once

Comment: Not Working still

Comment: I saw your data source is static i think `Data Source=DESKTOP-MP9NGB9` is this live datasource?